# I have a .nomedia file in a hidden folder on my phones internal storage

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage

I have a .nomedia file in a hidden folder on my phones internal storagefolder. What, where, when, why and how? I've deleted it a number of times and it just comes back in a new hidden folder. Is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe and even necessary for a hidden folder. This file says the system not to show pictures and videos from this folder in your Gallery, Video and similar apps.